# Installing both jupyter and notebook packages

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Recently my projects that use Jupyter Lab (supported by requiring pip to install `jupyter`) have stopped working in my IDE, which appears to rely on `notebook` to support Python notebook functionality. I've made no changes to my list of required packages for these projects, but it appears that until recently (Jupyter 4?) `notebook` just showed up, and now it doesn't and needs to be explicitly required to work in my IDE.

By explicitly requiring `notebook` I can get the IDE to work (though with a few warnings).

Did `jupyter` formerly install `notebook`? Is there a reason not to require both for scenarios like mine? Is there a better way to ensure that whenever `jupyter` is installed, `notebook` is also installed. Or is something else going on?

Comment: Dependency structure has inverted with JupyterLab 4/Notebook 7 release. Now Notebook depends on JupyterLab components not vice versa.

Comment: @krassowski Ah — so just require `notebook` instead of `jupyter` and I'm set? (If so that's an answer.)

Comment: @krassowski Indeed, replacing the requirement for `jupyter` with `notebook >=7.0` seems to fix it.